# Understanding the Phoenix miner log

Tags: mining, logs, solo-mining

I am running a phoenix miner for solo mining in my private network. I want to understand the logs of the miner. Can any one help me to understand the following more in depth especially the **shares** and **time**? What every term means?

`Eth speed: 7.264 MH/s, shares: 383/0/0, time: 18:37`

Answer (score 0):

Eth speed is of course the hashrate.

Shares are reported as *x*/*y*/*z*, where *x* is accepted shares, *y* is rejected shares, and *z* is incorrect shares.  If you're getting a significant number or rejected or incorrect shares you need to investigate, or at least restart the miner or reboot.  How to investigate--that's another question, so don't ask in a comment below, but generally you need to increase power, reduce memory overclocking, or reduce core underclocking.  It could also be due to a defect in the miner software or GPU drivers, etc., so lots of possible causes.

The time is simply the number of hours and minutes the miner has been running.